# Does steam track network usage in megabytes per second or megabits?

Tags: steam

When you download new content in Steam it will show you the current and historical network usage. Is this tracked in mega*bytes* or mega*bits*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Megabytes by default, but can be changed to megabits in the Downloads tab of the Settings/Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked, and it does indeed seem to be tracked in megabytes.

Comment: How did you check?

Answer (score -2):

It's in megabytes (or kilobytes etc... [and technically, *it may be* in MibiBytes, but I can't say for sure]).
You can tell the difference by looking at the symbol : `b` stands for bit, and `B` for Byte (i.e. 8 bits).

Comment: Why is this downvoted ? I ask genuinely, I'm quite new to SE (and Arqade.SE ) so I would like to know how I can improve this answer.